# Imported CSV in Gephi, but no chart displays

Tags: csv, gephi

I'm trying to visualize a set of topics, with their sub-topics, in Gephi.

Have imported the list of topics and sub-topics into Gephi from CSV, and looking at the 'Data Laboratory', I do see those 2 columns under Source and Target.

However, when I try to visualize the data, nothing happens. On the 'Overview' page, only a blank screen appears.

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you see the number of nodes and edges in the statistics? Perhaps the size of the graph is too small to be properly displayed and you might need to zoom in. It is just a wlid speculation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run into this problem before, and it usually comes from accidentally closing the "Graph" window.
To reopen it in the Overview view, click on the "Window" dropdown in the very top navbar, then click on "Graph".

[image: how to open up graph window in Gephi]

[image: opened up graph view]

Answer (score 1):

$ export LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 solved the problem for me!